# Windows - Driver development: Get global declared device objects from .sys file

Tags: c, windows, driver, disassembly

I have been already googling and looking arond in here already.

I found no similar question/answer regarding this topic.
I also think,this is not possible. But I could be wrong.

**History :**

Out if simple interest I just started to study an good old fashioned book by g. hoglund. It is called rootkits - subverting the windows kernel.
I just wanted to learn more about windows internals, but most important for me was, that I would like to get started somewhere to develop drivers and also learn about the history of driver development.

**Status:**

I decided and already started to write a nice ui tool with win32 api to load, register and unload my "out of the tutorial "legacy nt drivers for wxp on my virtual machine.
Now  I also thought about the possibility, not only to select a driver and load it to see its debug outputs, but also issue some commands, to invoke the major functions.
And I saw : You can define more than one device inside the source file(s).( this is surely not widely used, but it is possible ).

**Question:**

I would like to know, whether anybody ever made an attempt to read any of the DeviceObjects  declared globally inside the .sys file and if this person succeeded.
THX in advance.

Comment: What do You mean by reading all device objects declared globally inside .sys file, what is Your goal? To get device objects of given driver?

Comment: Right. I want to get all of them to display in a dropdown list in order to let the user(me) choose, to which device the commands are passed.

Comment: To sum up, You want to make a tool that loads Yours and only Your drivers, then show it's devices in the list. Actually If You are author of driver You know what devices You are creating. Please explain what do You mean by reading .sys file - what information do You think You can retrieve by parsing not yet loaded driver?

Comment: The driver must be loaded first. I will use SCM for that. Then i want to scan the sys file for all device variables inside it and then i would like to list them, with as much information as possible about the device. See it as an exercise.